# Android setting listener that does not exist on lower api

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility

I have read stuff about how to wrap things to be backward compatible but I can't get my arms around this one

I would like to do

```
TextToSpeech textToSpeech = ...
...
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 15){
   textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
   ...
   });
}
```

the problem is UtteranceProgressListener is api >= 15. I am targeting api 8 (I work for someone, I can't change this)

I was thinking of using `Class.forName(...)` but if I do that the code cannot compile (it is expecting a listener of type `UtteranceProgressListener`)

And if I do it, how can I implement the methods `@Override` of an object that is defined by a string ? At compile time Java doesn't know about them, right ?

Comment: You just have to use the else statement and setOnUtteranceCompletedListener()

Comment: that's what I did but Android Studio says this w ill be a compilation error

Comment: else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 4)

Answer (score 0):

Open up your androidmanifest.xml. Change your min api to 8. Make sure you update android api 8 using android tool.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: This is in my gradle file but I still get a warning in android studio. Is it a lint problem ?

Comment: class requires API level 15 (current min is 8): UtteranceProgressListener